# When using data.json file, textbox value is empty in Magicsuggest

Tags: jquery, json, magicsuggest

Here is my jQuery codes:

```
$('#keywords').magicSuggest({
    value: ["tehdit","hakaret", "yaralama"],
    data: "/data.json",
    width: 610
});
```

And here is my "data.json" file's content:

```
["tehdit","hakaret","yaralama","kişisel verilerin kaydedilmesi","TCK 106","iddianamenin iadesi","itiraz","basit yaralama","kişi hürriyetinden yoksun kılma","bir de bunu al","o olmadı bunu al","nunc","elementum","sagittis","sodales","ehliyetsiz oyuncak araba kullanma"]
```

Although it seems everything's fine, the keywords textbox is empty. "tehdit","hakaret" and "yaralama" are not inserted in the keywords textbox like this:
[image]
Could you help me, how do I this?

Answer (score 2):

(disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin)

Up to 1.3, the component wouldn't allow the developper to set values that weren't contained in the data set, which is why you were stuck. This was a choice by design so that values set would always be validated. Yet it would prevent scenarios like the one you are describing.

The latest 2.0 release now allows you to do that so you should be good if you update the project. It is now up to the developer to double check that the values set are valid.

Cheers